# The working copy needs to be upgraded - Eclipse/subclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

We made a branch of our project, and I have checked it out (via tortoise).

Now, I import the projects as Maven project.

From past experiences i know that I go **right-click->Team->Share** in order to register the project as a SVN project. This has always worked in the past.

Now I get this horrible error message when I click on the SVN element :

[image]

There are a number of other SO questions related to this error, but they all appear during the commit process.

Answer (score 1):

You either have to upgrade your local working copy to 1.8 scheme or to install an older version of your SVN connector in eclipse.

The easiest would be if you just use eclipse to checkout from SVN then you wouldn't have any version conflicts. Do you know about the m2e-subclipse connector which lets you directly import Maven projects from SVN?

Comment: so i assume my tortoise checked it out as 1.8 and Subclipse only recognises 1.9?

Comment: I think there is no 1.9. I think Tortoise is using pre 1.8 format. Eclipse uses an 1.8 plugin and wants to work with that format.